# How can I combine two xclip commands?

Tags: command-line, xorg, clipboard, mouse-click

Copy string into clipboard:

```
echo "hello world" | xclip  -sel clip
```

Copy string used by middle-click mouse button.

```
echo "hello world" | xclip
```

How can combine them as one?

```
echo "hello world" | xclip  -sel clip  &&  echo "hello world" | xclip
```

Is there a more simple way to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Kubuntu `xclip` supports `-filter`. From `man 1 xclip`:

> `-f`, `-filter`
> when `xclip` is invoked in the in mode with output level set to silent (the defaults), the filter option will cause `xclip` to print the text piped to standard in back to standard out unmodified

```
echo "hello world" | xclip -f -sel clip | xclip
```